# How to unlink a device from my google account

Tags: google, device-administrator

I gave my android to my daughter.  She cannot link the device to her own google account because it is linked to mine.  How can we unlink the android from my account without her loosing her data

Comment: You unlink your account and you lose your data. Then let her link here account and use it

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by unlinking your account, and that your daughter can't link her account? Usually, you just remove your account by going to Settings>Accounts>Google>Tap on account, then remove account. Then just add your daughter's account. If it's something else, please post more specifics.